# Updating a form with modal twitter bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am rendering data in a page and when i want to edit the data im using a twitter bootstrap modal and rendering a form, everything goes Ok but when i click in the submit button the page refresh completely. So i want when i click in the submit button the modal close and just refresh the data im rendering. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to work with ajax to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ajax for that. Typically you append `:remote => true` to your form

To this effect:
    <%= form_for(@post, :remote => true) do |f| %>
      ...
    <% end %>

Please take a look at the API for [FormHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).